# Laravel DatatableJs Invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

Iam working on Laravel project.. I face a problem with this Datatable it keep giving me "DataTables warning: table id=customer-table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/1"](http://datatables.net/tn/1%22) and I tried to dd($items) in controller but nothing hsppens I think it not seeing the function can you help me?

```
my controller is:
 public function getBasicData(Request $request){
        $items = Customers::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'customers.user_id')
                ->select('customers.*', 'users.username','users.active')
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

        return Datatables::of($items)
            ->editColumn('vehicle', function ($item) {
                
                return '<a href="'.route("customers.showvehicles", $item->id).'">Vehicle</a>';
            })
            ->editColumn('email_notification', function ($item) {
                dd($item);
                $template = 'emails.customer_notification';
                return '<a href="'.route("customer.mail", array($item->user_id, $template) ).'">Send</a>';
            })
             ->editColumn('created_at', function ($item) {
                return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item->created_at));
            })
            ->editColumn('active', function ($item) {
                if($item->active == 0)
                {
                    return 'Inactive';
                }
                else
                {
                    return 'Active';
                }
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function ($item) {

                $customer_name = ucfirst($item->name);
                return '<a href="'.route("customers.edit", $item->id).'" class="btn  btn-icon btn-flat" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit"><i class="far fa-edit text-dark"></i></a>
                <form action="'.route("customers.destroy", $item->id).'" method="post" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0;">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_confirm_cus_del" data-title="Delete Customer" data-message="Are you sure you want to delete this customer '.$customer_name.'  ?" 
                class="btn bg-transparent btn-clean btn-icon btn-flat  btnCustomerDelete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-cus_del_url="'.route("customers.destroy", $item->id).'" data-remove_button_id="'.$item->id.'"  id="cus_del_'.$item->id.'"
                 style="margin-top: 5px;height:22px;width:60px;"title="Delete"><i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i></button>
                </form>
                ';
            })
            ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
                if ($request->has('email') && $request->has('email') != '') {
                    $query->where('customers.email', '=', "{$request->get('email')}");
                }
                 if ($request->has('active') && $request->has('active') != '') {
                    $query->where('users.active', '=', "{$request->get('active')}");
                }
                if ($request->has('mobile') && $request->has('mobile') != '') {
                    $mob_num = "%".trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $request->get('mobile')))."%";
                    $query->whereRaw("(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(customers.mobile, '+', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')',''),' ','') LIKE ? )",[$mob_num]);
                }
                if ($request->has('telephone') && $request->has('telephone') != '') {
                    $telephone = "%".trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $request->get('telephone')))."%";
                    $query->whereRaw("(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(customers.telephone, '+', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')',''),' ','') LIKE ? )",[$telephone]);
                }
                if ($request->has('name') && $request->has('name') != '') {
                    $query->where('customers.name', 'like', "%{$request->get('name')}%");
                }
                if($request->has('plate') && $request->has('plate') != '') {
                    $query->join('vehicles', 'vehicles.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id');
                    //$query->where('vehicles.plate','=' ,'GJ12323');
                    $query->groupby('customers.id');
                    $query->where('vehicles.plate', 'like', "%{$request->get('plate')}%");
                }
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action', 'vehicle','created_at','email_notification','active'])
            ->make(true);
    }



    my blade is:


 @extends('layouts.blank') @push('stylesheets')
    <!-- Example -->
    <!--<link href=" <link href="{{ asset("css/myFile.min.css") }}" rel="stylesheet">" rel="stylesheet">-->
    @endpush @section('main_container')
    <!-- Start right Content here -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <div class="content-page">
      <!-- Start content -->
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- end row -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="card-box">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <p>@include('partials._flash')</p>
                    <div class="">
                      <table id="customer-table" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" 
                         style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
                
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Name</th>
                              <th>Email</th>
                              <th>Mobile</th>
                              <th>Tel</th>
                              <th>Vehicles</th>
                              <th>Created Date</th>
                              <th>Status</th>
                              <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end row -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end col-->
          </div>
          <!-- end row -->
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
      </div>
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <!-- End content-page -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- End Right content here -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    {{-- @include('includes.delete') --}}


    @endsection @push('scripts')
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.close_search').click(function() {
          $('body').find("input,select").val('').end();
        });

        $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
          "searching": false
        });
        var oTable = $('#customer-table').DataTable({
          // dom: 'Blrtip',
          // buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel'],
          // lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],    
          order: [
            [0, 'desc']
          ],
          responsive: true,
          processing: true,
          serverSide: true,
          filter: true,
          ajax: {
            // url: "{{ url('customers/getBasicData')}}",
            url: "{{route('customers.getBasicData')}}",
            data: function(d) {
              console.log(d);
              d.plate = $('input[name=plate]').val();
              d.name = $('input[name=name]').val();
              d.email = $('input[name=email]').val();
              d.mobile = $('input[name=mobile]').val();
              d.telephone = $('input[name=telephone').val();
              d.active = $('#active').val();
            }
          },
          displayLength: 10,
          lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
          columns: [{
              data: 'id',
              name: 'id',
              visible: false
            },
            {
              data: 'name',
              name: 'name'
            },
            {
              data: 'email',
              name: 'email'
            },
            {
              data: 'mobile',
              name: 'mobile'
            },
            {
              data: 'telephone',
              name: 'telephone'
            },
            {
              data: 'vehicle',
              name: 'vehicle',
              orderable: false,
              searchable: false
            },
            {
              data: 'created_at',
              name: 'created_at'
            },
            {
              data: 'active',
              name: 'active'
            },
            {
              data: 'action',
              name: 'action',
              orderable: false,
              searchable: false,
              className: 'text-center',
              width: '100px'
            },
          ],
          columnDefs: [{
              targets: 0,
              orderable: false,
              responsivePriority: 1,
            },
            {
              targets: -1,
              responsivePriority: 3,
            }
          ],
          language: {
            "decimal": "",
            "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
            "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
            "infoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
            "infoPostFix": "",
            "thousands": ",",
            "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
            "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
            "processing": "<div class='text-blue'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-5x fa-spin'></i><p>Working, Please wait ..</p></div>",
            "search": "Search:",
            "zeroRecords": "No matching records found",
            "paginate": {
              "first": "First",
              "last": "Last",
              "next": "Next",
              "previous": "Previous"
            },
            "aria": {
              "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
              "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
            }
          },
        });
        $(function() {
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        });
        $('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
          oTable.draw();
          //$('.bs-example-modal-sm').hide();
          $('.bs-example-modal-sm').modal('hide');
          e.preventDefault();
        });


        $('#modal_confirm_cus_del').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          $message = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-message');
          del_url = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-cus_del_url');
          remove_button_id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-remove_button_id');
          $(this).find('.modal-body p').text($message);
          $title = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-title');
          $(this).find('.modal-title').text($title);

          $('#modal_confirm_cus_del').find('.modal-footer #confirm_delete_customer').attr('data-cus_del_url', del_url);
          $('#modal_confirm_cus_del').find('.modal-footer #confirm_delete_customer').attr('data-remove_button_id', remove_button_id);

          // Pass form reference to modal for submission on yes/ok
          // var form = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('form');
          //$(this).find('.modal-footer #confirm').data('form', form);
        });

        $('#modal_confirm_cus_del').find('.modal-footer #confirm_delete_customer').on('click', function() {
          //$(this).data('form').submit();

          var that = $(this);

          that.prop('disabled', true);

          del_url = that.data('cus_del_url');
          remove_button_id = that.data('remove_button_id');

          $.ajax({
            url: del_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
              _method: 'delete'
            },
            success: function(result) {
              $('#modal_confirm_cus_del').modal('hide');
              $('#cus_del_' + remove_button_id).closest('tr').remove();
              that.prop('disabled', false);
              location.reload();
            },
            complete: function() {
              that.prop('disabled', false);
            }
          });

        });
        $(function() {
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        });

      });
    </script>
    @endpush
```

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser to see if the ajax response is in correct format or not.

Comment: it give me in network response : this request has no response data